# Angular 13 Update "Duplicate identifier" Error

Tags: angular, angular-ivy

I am maintaining a private npm-package that provides angular-components. I am trying to update the package to angular 13 (from angular 12) and got everything to work, so I released a new version to npm. When I tried to use the package I get several errors like the following:

`TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'ɵdir'.`

`TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'ɵfac'.`

I changed the `angularCompilerOptions` to use `"compilatonMode": "partial"` and removed the option `"enableIvy": false`, released a new version but I still get the same errors.

Does anybody have any ideas what I'm doing wrong or any pointers what might cause this issue? Thank you a lot stackoverflow community. :)

**EDIT**: One interesting observation is that after an `npm install` in the consuming package, the files in `node_modules/my-package` (here the `accordion.d.ts` as an example) look something like this:

```
import { AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CdkAccordion } from '@angular/cdk/accordion';
import * as i0 from "@angular/core";
export declare class Accordion extends CdkAccordion implements AfterContentInit {
    private _keyManager;
    private _headers;
    ngAfterContentInit(): void;
    private radio;
    private _handleHeaderKeydown;
    private _handleHeaderFocus;
    static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<Accordion, never>;
    static ɵdir: i0.ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration<Accordion, "accordion", ["Accordion"], { "multi": "multi"; "radio": "radio"; }, {}, ["_headers"]>;
}
```

as soon as I start the app (with `npm start` which calls `ng serve`), the file changes to:

```
import { AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CdkAccordion } from '@angular/cdk/accordion';
import * as i0 from "@angular/core";
import * as ɵngcc0 from '@angular/core';
export declare class Accordion extends CdkAccordion implements AfterContentInit {
    private _keyManager;
    private _headers;
    ngAfterContentInit(): void;
    private radio;
    private _handleHeaderKeydown;
    private _handleHeaderFocus;
    static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<Accordion, never>;
    static ɵdir: i0.ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration<Accordion, "accordion", ["Accordion"], { "multi": "multi"; "radio": "radio"; }, {}, ["_headers"]>;
    static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<Accordion, never>;
    static ɵdir: ɵngcc0.ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration<Accordion, never, never, {}, {}, never>;
}

//# sourceMappingURL=accordion.d.ts.map
```

So the error message kind of makes sense about the duplicated identifiers `efac` and `edir`, but why would it do that? Also note the import of ɵngcc0 which was added after `ng serve`.

Comment: I think it has to do with cache you have from your last build, maybe

Comment: Did you try uninstalling node_mdoules and npm install again?

Comment: I deleted both `node_modules` and the `package-lock.json` in both the component-library (before releasing) and in the consuming project, so I don't think that's the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a similar issue on [github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35394#issuecomment-598398098) and managed to get it working by deleting the metadata.json file which was in `node_modules/my-package/my-package.metadata.json`. After checking the `/dist` folder of my component-library I found the metadata.json file there as well, so I deleted it and rebuild it. Now the file was not generated again. Problem solved I guess ‍♂️

Hope that helps other people. And as a side note: I guess it would make sense to change the build process so that `/dist` gets cleared before building.